# How to check Google Play Protect status?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-protect

I'm creating an anti-virus software, and I would like to know if Google Play Protect is enabled or disabled? I'm using Java in Android Studio. Are there any permissions required to access this information?

Comment: I don't think there's an API for this, although I'm not certain.  What is your use-case, out of curiosity?

Comment: I am working on mobile anti-virus software.if I think of sending notifications to the user according to play protect status

Comment: Okay, I looked a bit more and there is in fact an API.  Adding an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if Google Play Protect (also known as Verify Apps) is enabled using the [SafetyNet Verify Apps API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/verify-apps.html#determine-verification-enabled) (see that link for more details, including a Kotlin version and an option to prompt the user to enable it if it's disabled).

It's an asynchronous API, so you'll have to write a callback, something like:

```java
SafetyNet.getClient(context)
    .isVerifyAppsEnabled()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<VerifyAppsUserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<VerifyAppsUserResponse> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                VerifyAppsUserResponse result = task.getResult();
                if (result.isVerifyAppsEnabled()) {
                    // It's enabled, handle that case here
                } else {
                    // It's not enabled, handle that case here
                }
            } else {
                // An error occurred, we don't know whether it's enabled
            }
        }
    });
```

The `context` parameter would just be your `this` if you're calling it from an `Activity` or `Service`.